# How to configure proposals for IPSEC rekeying

Tags: ipsec, strongswan

I have a VPN connection via IPSEC (strongswan) running successfully. However, at least once a day the connection breaks. I think it has to do with rekeying, see the logs:

```
Aug 25 02:34:25 myserver charon: 09[KNL] creating rekey job for CHILD_SA ESP/0xcbd335d0/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Aug 25 02:34:25 myserver charon: 10[IKE] establishing CHILD_SA infonline_datapool{2} reqid 1
Aug 25 02:34:25 myserver charon: 12[CFG] received proposals: ESP:AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_256_128/MODP_2048/NO_EXT_SEQ
Aug 25 02:34:25 myserver charon: 12[CFG] configured proposals: ESP:AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA1_96/MODP_2048/NO_EXT_SEQ, ESP:AES_CBC_128/AES_CBC_192/AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_256_128/HMAC_SHA2_384_192/HMAC_SHA
2_512_256/HMAC_SHA1_96/AES_XCBC_96/NO_EXT_SEQ
Aug 25 02:34:25 myserver charon: 12[IKE] no acceptable proposal found
Aug 25 02:34:25 myserver charon: 12[IKE] failed to establish CHILD_SA, keeping IKE_SA
Aug 25 02:34:25 myserver charon: 12[IKE] sending DELETE for ESP CHILD_SA with SPI cbd2f4c3
Aug 25 02:34:25 myserver charon: 11[IKE] CHILD_SA rekeying failed, trying again in 10 seconds
Aug 25 02:34:35 myserver charon: 15[IKE] establishing CHILD_SA infonline_datapool{3} reqid 1
Aug 25 02:34:35 myserver charon: 06[CFG] received proposals: ESP:AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_256_128/MODP_2048/NO_EXT_SEQ
Aug 25 02:34:35 myserver charon: 06[CFG] configured proposals: ESP:AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA1_96/MODP_2048/NO_EXT_SEQ, ESP:AES_CBC_128/AES_CBC_192/AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_256_128/HMAC_SHA2_384_192/HMAC_SHA
2_512_256/HMAC_SHA1_96/AES_XCBC_96/NO_EXT_SEQ
Aug 25 02:34:35 myserver charon: 06[IKE] no acceptable proposal found
Aug 25 02:34:35 myserver charon: 06[IKE] failed to establish CHILD_SA, keeping IKE_SA
Aug 25 02:34:35 myserver charon: 06[IKE] sending DELETE for ESP CHILD_SA with SPI c068db7b
Aug 25 02:34:35 myserver charon: 07[IKE] received DELETE for ESP CHILD_SA with SPI c7a90494
Aug 25 02:34:35 myserver charon: 07[IKE] closing CHILD_SA infonline_datapool{1} with SPIs cbd335d0_i (34701240 bytes) c7a90494_o (451113 bytes) and TS yyy.yyy.yyy.0/25 === 10.10.42.0/24
Aug 25 02:34:35 myserver charon: 07[IKE] sending DELETE for ESP CHILD_SA with SPI cbd335d0
Aug 25 02:34:35 myserver charon: 07[IKE] CHILD_SA closed
Aug 25 02:34:35 myserver charon: 07[IKE] detected CHILD_REKEY collision with CHILD_DELETE
Aug 25 02:34:35 myserver charon: 09[IKE] received DELETE for unknown ESP CHILD_SA with SPI 632d34ba
Aug 25 02:34:35 myserver charon: 09[IKE] CHILD_SA closed
Aug 25 02:34:35 myserver charon: 10[IKE] received DELETE for unknown ESP CHILD_SA with SPI 632d34ba
Aug 25 02:34:35 myserver charon: 10[IKE] CHILD_SA closed
Aug 25 02:34:35 myserver charon: 12[IKE] received DELETE for IKE_SA infonline_datapool[1]
Aug 25 02:34:35 myserver charon: 12[IKE] deleting IKE_SA infonline_datapool[1] between xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]...yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy[yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy]
Aug 25 02:34:35 myserver charon: 12[IKE] IKE_SA deleted
```

I guess the key lines here are:

```
Aug 25 02:34:25 myserver charon: 12[CFG] received proposals: ESP:AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_256_128/MODP_2048/NO_EXT_SEQ
Aug 25 02:34:25 myserver charon: 12[CFG] configured proposals: ESP:AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA1_96/MODP_2048/NO_EXT_SEQ, ESP:AES_CBC_128/AES_CBC_192/AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_256_128/HMAC_SHA2_384_192/HMAC_SHA
2_512_256/HMAC_SHA1_96/AES_XCBC_96/NO_EXT_SEQ
Aug 25 02:34:25 myserver charon: 12[IKE] no acceptable proposal found
```

The config is

```
conn conn_name
    type=tunnel
    authby=secret
    left=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    leftsubnet=xxx.xxx.xxx.0/25
    right=yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
    rightsubnet=10.10.42.0/24
    ike=aes256-sha256-modp2048
    ikelifetime=86400s
    esp=aes256-sha1-modp2048
    pfs=yes
    auto=start
```

How do I configure the connection so that it doesn't break? (When I restart ipsec, it connects just fine.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analysis is spot-on, you now just have to draw the right conclusions :)

You can see the algorithms the peer proposes in the log messages you pointed out. Since you configured SHA-1 and the peer proposes SHA-256 there is no match (the default proposal that follows the one you configured does include SHA-256, but no DH groups, so that doesn't match either).

So the fix is quite simple, configure `esp=aes256-sha256-modp2048`.

Comment: Ouch, totally missed that, don't know why that line is different from the `ike` line. Thanks for the quick answer, will let you know if it works. Do you know why the connection gets established successfully but then later breaks?

Comment: During the IKE_AUTH exchange, the DH groups are stripped from the ESP proposals because the keys for the CHILD_SA are derived from the IKE key material (no separate DH exchange). So the default proposal, which includes both AES-256 and SHA-256, matches just fine. During the rekeying, the DH group is relevant and, as I mentioned, that proposal doesn't match anymore.

Comment: Awesome, thank you, everything is stable since I fixed the config!